Why such a variable 'ext' in 'iloiterator.h' is undefined when I use CPLEX with C++?
When I'm reproducing the code from a paper, I encountered CPLEX for the first time. I followed the methods provided in the CPLEX documentation to set up the necessary libraries and compilation options. However, when running the code, I encountered an error indicating an undeclared identifier. The output information is as follows:
Build started at 9:50...
1>------ Build started: Project: replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(88,17): error C2065: 'ext': undeclared identifier
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(88,17):
1>the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
1>  C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(94,2):
1>  see reference to class template instantiation 'IloIterator<E>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(88,27): warning C4346: 'ImplClass': dependent name is not a type
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(88,27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'ImplClass'
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(91,25): error C2065: 'ext': undeclared identifier
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(91,14): warning C4346: 'ImplClass': dependent name is not a type
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\concert\include\ilconcert\iloiterator.h(91,14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'ImplClass'
1>(compiling source file 'main.cpp')
1>D:\0_Master0\Adapt_cmsa_mdmwnpp\replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1\replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1\main.cpp(84,12): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>D:\0_Master0\Adapt_cmsa_mdmwnpp\replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1\replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1\main.cpp(751,17): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>Done building project "replication-adapt-cmsa+la-vs-v1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 9:50 and took 02.923 seconds ==========

There's another error shows that error C2061: Syntax error: identifier "ImplClass"
The codes in iloiterator.h from line 1 to line 91 are shown as follows:
// -------------------------------------------------------------- -*- C++ -*-
// File: ./include/ilconcert/iloiterator.h
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
//
// 5725-A06 5725-A29 5724-Y47 5724-Y48 5724-Y49 5724-Y54 5724-Y55 5655-Y21
// Copyright IBM Corp. 2000, 2013
//
// US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
// disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with
// IBM Corp.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef __CONCERT_iloiteratorH
#define __CONCERT_iloiteratorH

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma pack(push, 8)
#endif

#include <ilconcert/iloextractable.h>

class IloBaseIterator {
private:
    IloEnvI*                     _env;
    class IloTypedList*          _list;
    class IloTypedList*          _current;

    IloBool                      _withSubClasses;
public:
    IloBaseIterator(const IloEnv env, IloBool withSubClasses = IloTrue)
        : _env(env.getImpl())
        , _list(0)
        , _current(0)
        , _withSubClasses(withSubClasses)
    {}
    void goToNextNonEmptyList(IloLinkedList<IloExtractableI>::Iterator& _iter);
    void init(IloRtti::TypeInfo typeInfo, IloLinkedList<IloExtractableI>::Iterator &_iter);
};

template <class E>

class IloIterator : public IloBaseIterator {
private:
    IloExtractableList::Iterator _iter;

#if defined(ILO_HP_aCC) || defined(ILO_LINUX) || defined(ILO_APPLE)
    typedef typename E::ImplClass EImplClass;
#endif

    void init() {
#if defined(ILO_HP_aCC) || defined(ILO_LINUX) || defined(ILO_APPLE)
        IloBaseIterator::init(EImplClass::GetTypeInfo(), _iter);
#else
        IloBaseIterator::init(E::ImplClass::GetTypeInfo(), _iter);
#endif
    }

public:
    
    IloIterator(const IloEnv env, IloBool withSubClasses = IloTrue)
        : IloBaseIterator(env,withSubClasses),
        _iter(IloExtractableList())
    {
        init();
    }

    
    IloBool ok() { return _iter.ok(); }
    
    void operator++() {
        ++_iter;
        if (!_iter.ok()) { IloBaseIterator::goToNextNonEmptyList(_iter); }
    }

    E operator*() {
#if defined(ILO_HP_aCC) || defined(ILO_LINUX) || defined(ILO_APPLE)
        EImplClass* ext = (EImplClass*)*_iter;
        IloAssert(ext->isType(EImplClass::GetTypeInfo()),
            "Bad extractable type in IloKindOfIterator::operator*");
        return (EImplClass*)ext;
#elif defined(ILO_RS6000)
        typename E::ImplClass *ext = (typename E::ImplClass*)*_iter;
        IloAssert(ext->isType(E::ImplClass::GetTypeInfo()),
            "Bad extractable type in IloKindOfIterator::operator*");
        return (typename E::ImplClass*)ext;
#else
        E::ImplClass* ext = (E::ImplClass*)*_iter;
        IloAssert(ext->isType(E::ImplClass::GetTypeInfo()),
            "Bad extractable type in IloKindOfIterator::operator*");
        return (E::ImplClass*)ext;
#endif
    }
};

I'm confused with these two errors.
After searching, I try to change the line 88 E::ImplClass* ext = (E::ImplClass*)*_iter; into typename E::ImplClass* ext = (typename E::ImplClass*)*_iter;. But the file iloiterator.h can't be modified.  How can I solve this problem?
